# Where is googleapi compute.zoneOperations.wait? Trying to create Google VM instances in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to use the type-safe Google cloud compute API in Typescript: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/zoneOperations/wait. The doc says it should be available in beta, but in my IDE and in my app, using `googleapis@46.0.0`, I can see that `wait` is only available as an "alpha", not in "beta" or "v1". The error I see in the app is `TypeError: compute.zoneOperations.wait is not a function`. And I've found that normal users can't use alpha functions without some special Google-fu.
So my question is, how can I use `zoneOperations.wait`?

Simplified, this is my code to create a VM instance:

```js
import { google } from 'googleapis'
// ...
  const authClient = await google.auth.getClient({
    scopes: [...]
  })
  const projectId = await google.auth.getProjectId()
  const request = {
    project: projectId,
    zone: zone,
    resource: vmConfig,
    auth: authClient,
  };
  const response = await compute.instances.insert(request)
  const operationId = response.data.id
  if (!operationId)
    throw new Error(`createInstance: Error creating instance ${vmName}`)

  // Wait for the instance to be created: this is where it fails
  const status = await compute.zoneOperations.wait({operation: operationId})
```

Note that the instance *does* get created OK (I can see it in the console.)
I know I could call `zoneOperations.get` in a loop, but that's wasteful and slow because I have to sleep in between calls.

Anyone out there using this API to create VM instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked internally, our product engineers are working to generate the client library for the compute.zoneOperations.wait method early 2020. However, the release ETA cannot be shared at this moment.

keep in mind that support does not cover [Alpha releases](https://cloud.google.com/terms/launch-stages). Product
teams directly manage Alpha release participation and the respective feedback
channels without involvement of the support team.

If you have questions regarding an Alpha release or participation in an Alpha
program, please reach out to your [account team or Sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact/).

Comment: Thanks very much, I appreciate the info! But I do note that according to the doc, `wait` is now in beta. I'll look forward to using this when it's regenerated into this module.

Comment: You are welcome. Indeed, it is only a discovery-based client for GCE (no gRPC client). The client libraries will be available to users after the lunch.